# Coordinates to graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is there a simpler, easier way to convert coordinates (long, lat) to a "[networkx](https://networkx.github.io/)"-graph, than nested looping over those coordinates and adding weighted nodes/edges for each one?

```
for idx1, itm1 in enumerate(data):
    for idx2, itm2 in enumerate(data):
            pos1 = (itm1["lng"], itm1["lat"])
            pos2 = (itm2["lng"], itm2["lat"])
            distance = vincenty(pos1, pos2).meters #geopy distance
            # print(idx1, idx2, distance)
            graph.add_edge(idx1, idx2, weight=distance)
```

The target is representing points as a graph in order to use several functions on this graph.

Edit: Using an adjacency_matrix would still need a nested loop

Comment: For sure you can move third line one up :)

Comment: it is likely to be quicker to create a list of tuples and then call `graph.add_weighted_edges_from(edge_list)` where the form of your edge list will be `[(pos1, pos2, distance), ....]`

Comment: So - to be clear you have an input list `data` which consists of a bunch of coordinates and you want to create a graph with a node for each coordinate and an edge between each pair of coordinates which has a weight equal to the distance between those coordinates?

Comment: @Joel: Yes. Each data set is represented by latitude and longitude as "float". In my case (on short distances) their weight is equal to their point to point distance (pythagoras). So i'm looking for a single loop solution which transfers a 2d set of points in to it's corresponding "graph-representation".

Comment: So if @Aric didn't point out a built-in `networkx` function, then I think it's safe to say there isn't one.  I don't think you'll do better than the answer he gave.  As long as you understand how to modify the `edges = ` line of his code to adjust for your data, I think that's as good as you can do.  If it's not clear, make a comment and I'll give a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do some kind of loop. But if you are using an undirected graph you can eliminate half of the graph.add_edge() (only need to add u-v and not v-u).  Also as @EdChum suggests you can use graph.add_weighted_edges_from() to make it go faster.

Here is a nifty way to do it

```
In [1]: from itertools import combinations

In [2]: import networkx as nx

In [3]: data = [10,20,30,40]

In [4]: edges = ( (s[0],t[0],s[1]+t[1]) for s,t in combinations(enumerate(data),2))

In [5]: G = nx.Graph()

In [6]: G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)

In [7]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[7]: 
[(0, 1, {'weight': 30}),
 (0, 2, {'weight': 40}),
 (0, 3, {'weight': 50}),
 (1, 2, {'weight': 50}),
 (1, 3, {'weight': 60}),
 (2, 3, {'weight': 70})]
```